# Jump Continuity of the function $f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$

Tags: limits, analysis, functions, continuity

With trying with examples, I found that
the function $$f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$ has a jump continuity when $a\cdot \frac{-d}{c} + b = 0$ at point
$(-d/c, \frac{a+b}{c+d})$

However, I could not find a calculation that leads to the result $y_0 = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$. I somehow failed to calculate the limit of $\lim_{x\rightarrow-d/c}f(x)$.
What am I missing here?

Comment: When $x=-d/c$, the function $f$ is undefined.

Comment: when $ad-bc=0$   the function is constant, graph a line. Otherwise the graph is a hyperbola.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes I understand that. Just I cannot get the $\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ with the calculation

Comment: Since it's a horizontal line, it's a constant and you can pick almost any $x$ value to plug in. Technically this won't work when $c+d=0$, since that'd be equivalent to plugging in to make $f(1)$, which is undefined. So you can choose a different value, like $f(0)=\frac b d$ or $\frac a c$.

Comment: @Merosity Oh, now I understand, just put some values in XD. Thank you!

Comment: I have heard of a jump discontinuity before, but I have not heard a jump continuity.  Your question would be clearer if you defined what you meant by a jump continuity.

Comment: your function has a **vertical asymptote**, *not* a jump discontinuity(where the discontinuous intervals end at finite values)